# countBy using underscore - pick count avoiding duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Could be the simplest but still. From the below data, I actually wanted to implement _.countBy to get response as there is 1 from City A and 1 from City B. The catch here is, first and second record actually refers to the same person. So logically there is one person from City A. But countBy result in 2 from City A and 1 from City B with respect to records present. Could you please help solve this?

```
 var data=[{
      id:1,
      name:"xxx",
      city:"City A",
      skill:"Angular"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"xxx",
      city:"City A",
      skill:"Node"
    },{
      id:3,
      name:"yyy",
      city:"City B",
      skill:"Angular"
    }];
```

Comment: @SunnyPatel You indeed understood the problem so right and i was much amazed by the solution you came up with. Am really really sorry for procrastinating responding to this. Your effort is much appreciated and am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that each user is unique first by using [`_.uniq`](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq) before passing it to [`_.countBy`](https://underscorejs.org/#countBy). To ensure values are unique, I just created a string by concatenating the city with the name with a pipe (`|`) delimiter.

```
const unique = _.uniq(data, p => p.city + "|" + p.name)
const byCity = _.countBy(unique, p => p.city)
```

You can combine both into a single line using [`_.chain`](https://underscorejs.org/#chain).

```
_.chain(data).uniq(p => p.city + "|" + p.name).countBy(p => p.city).value()
```

Both return the result of:

> ```
> {  
>     City A: 1,
>     City B: 1
> }
> ```